# defaultHighLight of solr3.6 does not work?

Tags: solr, lucene, highlight

I am using solr 3.6.2 and I found the default highlight does not work like solr 1.4.1. 
Is it a bug?

example:

- I use 2gram tokenizer.
- text: `testabctest123456testabc`
- index: `te es st ta ab bc ct te es st t1 12 23 ・・・`
- query: `test`

parameters:

```
hl=true 
hl.fragsize=200 
hl.simple.pre={{{ 
hl.simple.post=}}} 
hl.highlightMultiTerm=true 
hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true
```

At solr 3.6.2 the default highlight result is: `{{{testabctest123456test}}}abc`

At solr 1.4.1 the highlight result is: `{{{test}}}abc{{{test}}}123456{{{test}}}abc`

At solr 3.6.2 the FastVectorHighlighter resutlt is: `{{{test}}}abc{{{test}}}123456{{{test}}}abc`

What happened to the default highlight in solr 3.6?

Though the `FastVectorHighlighter` works well, I need to use default highlight.

Comment: I found someone had customised the solr1.4 default highlight before I joined the team. so It is not a bug.
The standard solr1.4 default highlighter works like solr3.6.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a bug.  That's how the highlighter works.  If it finds multiple matches within the same term, it wraps them all.  There does not appear to be any sort of configuration to change this behavior, I don't believe.

Seems like using the Highlighter implementation that does what you want would be the logical approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Though it is not a bug , I need it works like solr1.4 or FastVectorHighlighter.

Comment: If it does what you want, why don't you want to use `FastVectorHighlighter`?

Comment: If I use FastVectorHighlighter, the index size is larger than default highlight. The size will be double. so the replication's time becomes longer.In my case, I want to use FastVectorHighlighter,but I can not use FastVectorHighlighter.